# How to get path of a folder contaning .app file in MacOSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a query regarding path of a folder in Mac OSX. I have to find the current folder from where my app is executed/located.

Suppose that I have a Folder name 'ROOTFOLDER' having two files

1. MyApp.app
2. MyText.txt

Now I have to find the path of the 'ROOTFOLDER' in my code. Any idea or suggestion would be great. I am developing an enterprise Mac app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSBundle`'s `mainBundle` class method gives you an `NSBundle` instance for your app's bundle. Once you have that you can use the `bundleURL` or `bundlePath` properties to get the app' URL or path. Finally use `NSURL` or `NSString` path methods, for URL and path respectively, to get the parent folder.